# Перенос вопроса с основного сайта на Мету

Tags: обсуждение, перенос-вопросов

Например, вопрос задали на основном сайте. А тематика соответствует мета-разделу. У нас есть возможность переместить вопрос на Мету?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В причинах закрытия есть специальный пункт:

> [image: Перенос на Мету]

Comment: ой, ой. а это доступно мне?

Comment: @Flippy, если можешь голосовать за закрытие - значит доступно